# Objective-C Tested app on iPhone, updated data, data doesnt change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I just built my first app and now I started testing it on my phone. It looks great when I first launch the app after building it, the launch images appears and then my json data is loaded via NSURL and displays properly on the app. But when I close down the app, update the data via php and mysql and re open it the launch image does not appear and my app is not updated. Is it possible to have the app launch like it did when I first launched it, always have launch image and also get the new data?

Here is my code if it helps.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadJSON];
}


- (void)loadJSON
{

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error" message: @"Connection Failed" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Refresh" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show]; [alert release];
        });
    } else {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/GetData.php"];

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];

            NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            NSArray *firstItemArray = array[0];

            NSString *yesNoString = firstItemArray[0];
            NSString *dateString = firstItemArray[1];
            NSString *timeString = firstItemArray[2];
            NSString *homeString = firstItemArray[3];
            NSString *awayString = firstItemArray[4];
            NSString *lastUpdatedString = firstItemArray[5];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.YesOrNo.text = yesNoString;
                self.date.text = [@"For " stringByAppendingString:dateString];
                self.time.text = timeString;
                self.home.text = homeString;
                self.away.text = awayString;
                self.lastUpdated.text = lastUpdatedString;
                self.lastUpdatedText.text = @"Last Updated";
                self.vs.text = @"vs";
            });
        });
    }

}




- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self loadJSON];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_YesOrNo release];
    [_date release];
    [_time release];
    [_vs release];
    [_home release];
    [_away release];
    [_lastUpdatedText release];
    [_lastUpdated release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great and appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As a recommendation, try to use a library as AFNetworking or Restkit to communicate with the server. Second, maybe the server or maybe the iPhone is using a cached version of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hit the round home button when running an app, it just puts it into the background, where it continues to run in a type of catatonic state.  When you tap its icon again, it just wakes up, and doesn't re-launch.  If you'd like to have your app completely quit when the user hits the home button, use the info.plist option "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" also known as "Application does not run in background."  Set this to YES in your info.plist, and you'll get a fresh start every time.  You can access this by clicking on your project in Xcode in the Project Navigator mode, and select the "info" tab at the top middle.

Answer (score 1):

As it is your first app, you should try reading about the various devices and os versions.
Read about various application states, also the methods that are present in the AppDelegateClass, that get called when the app enters into various states,try reading about them.

So what has happened in your case is the device that you are using is Multitasking one. So when you press the home button or the sleep button the game goes to background, and is not killed. So next time when you tap on the application icon on your device, it brings it back to the foreground and does not relaunch it hence your Viewdidload method won't be called and your changes won't get reflected.

So, now to terminate your app, you can go through this link
http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/02/10/how-to-close-apps-on-iphone/

Hope this helps.